# Getting logged in user info

Tags: c#, postgresql, winforms, authentication

This is my code so far:

```
private void loginbtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        CRUD.cmd = new NpgsqlCommand("SELECT COUNT(*) FROM users WHERE username = '" + txtuser.Text + "' AND password = '" + txtpass.Text + "'", CRUD.con);
        NpgsqlDataAdapter da = new NpgsqlDataAdapter();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        da.SelectCommand = CRUD.cmd;
        da.Fill(dt);

        if (dt.Rows[0][0].ToString() == "1")
        {
            Welcome welcome = new Welcome();
            welcome.Show();

            this.Hide();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Username or password incorrect, try again.",
                "Error", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
            txtpass.Clear();
            txtuser.Clear();
            txtuser.Focus();

        }
        if (RememberMe.Checked)
        {
            Properties.Settings.Default.UserName = txtuser.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Password = txtpass.Text;
            Properties.Settings.Default.Save();
        }
    }
```

I know I should use SQL Parameters, but it's a safe local environment. My question is, how can I retrieve info of which user is currently logged in? I need it so when the user does INSERT method to SQL table, I want to know which user did the entry or which user deleted it. Also to add that users info together with the rest of INSERT method to 2 additional columns (USER ID AND PASS).

Edit:

What I have here is a small windows form application with a datagridview (DGV) and a few text fields to insert values to table with a button, then display that info to DGV, with the ability to delete rows also. I made Form2 so the user has to log in before he gains access to Form1 (DGV Form). All I want to do is to somehow save that users info and whenever he makes a change to DGV, add his credentials to 2 extra columns in the table next to the entry that he has made.

Comment: well, instead of just _counting_ the users, matching your username and unhashed password (which you should ***never*** do, even in a safe local environment. and especially if you're still learning - learn it right!), you could just `SELECT *` and read the data?

Comment: You can retrieve user name or user domain name from window environment like this doc "https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.environment.username?view=net-5.0" let's hope that your pc environment and AD properly setup

Comment: @FranzGleichmann Thank you, I'm not very familiar with hashed passwords, yet. Not entirely sure of how I should implement the SELECT * method to find currently logged in user, could you give me a small example?
Environment.UserName gets me the current user on windows, I need to grab a user that is currently logged in in my app

Comment: Save the user name and password in a reference, what's the issue here? Also make sure to clarify your questions, otherwise people misinterpreted them, and you get closed a duplicate. I have removed the duplicate i have added. Can you edit the question and be more specific about what you actually need. I found this a little ambiguous

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear what I'm trying to do. Sorry if I misunderstood something, I'm still a newbie with windows forms.

Comment: `I know I should use SQL Parameters, but it's a safe local environment.` No excuse. Do it properly, every time. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14376473/what-are-good-ways-to-prevent-sql-injection https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1054022/best-way-to-store-password-in-database

Comment: `My question is, how can I retrieve info of which user is currently logged in?` They must have logged in when they loaded the app, yes? So store the username at that point in a `static` variable.

Comment: Thank you guys, It's a test app so I'm not worried by SQL injections. Just trying to learn some new things, I'll try to sort it out somehow..

Comment: `so I'm not worried by SQL injections.` I want to be crystal clear here - this is not how to develop software.

Comment: @mjwills Yeah and I totally agree with you on that one, I just learned about parameters and sql injections 10 days into this test project, so I decided to at least make it work before I go and change every mistake I made during the build.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Knowing who is logged in

#### Who is logged in to the windows machine

In case you're referring to who is logged in to eg. the Windows machine, you could use something like `Environment.UserName`.

#### Custom solution / database

If it's your own solution / database to "log in" to, that's a feature you'd need to add.
It's usually done on its own server with well-known libraries instead of being 'hand-written', but for a crude/insecure example for your test project you could use `Properties.Settings`, eg:

```
/* "Logging in" */
if (password == databaseUser.Password) {
    Properties.Settings.Default.myLoggedInUserId = databaseUser.Id;
    Properties.Settings.Default.myLoggedInUserName = databaseUser.Name;
}

/* "Logging out" */
Properties.Settings.Default.myLoggedInUserId = null;
Properties.Settings.Default.myLoggedInUserName = null;
```

## Which user created/edited a row

This is often implemented by adding additional fields to the table, eg. `CreatedDate` and `CreatedBy`:

```
var sqlText = "INSERT INTO MyTableName(Name, CreationDate, CreatedBy) VALUES (@Name, @CreatedDate, @CreatedBy);";
var command = new SqlCommand(sqlText, connection);

command.Parameters.Add("@Name", name);
command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedDate", DateTime.UtcNow);
command.Parameters.Add("@CreatedBy", myLoggedInUserName);
```

For who edited a row, consider "modified date" and "modified by" columns.

## Who Deleted a row

This could be done either by:

- manually `INSERT`ing into another table after the action is successful (which it sounds like you have)

  ```
  DELETE FROM Users WHERE UserId = @UserId;
  INSERT INTO MyLoggingTable(LogMessage, LoggedInUserId)
    VALUES(@Message, @LoggedInUserId);
  ```
- when combined with "modified date"/"modified by" columns as mentioned above, using a "soft delete" which deletes by setting a property rather than an SQL `DELETE`, eg `users.Active`:

  ```
  --List all active users
  SELECT * FROM users WHERE users.Active = 1;

  --Delete a user
  UPDATE users SET Active = 0 WHERE UserId = @UserId;

  --Who deleted a user (assuming you can't edit a deleted user)
  SELECT users.ModifiedBy FROM users WHERE users.UserId = @Id;
  ```
- similar to the above section, but adding "deleted date" and "deleted by" columns (may be needed if its still possible to modify something that is 'inactive')

Comment: That's a really good answer, thank you Shameen!